# how to cut float version numbers + linux

Tags: shell-script, awk, string

how to get only the two first digit from the following command

my target is to get the hadoop basic version

```
hdp-select | grep hadoop-client | awk '{print $NF}'
2.6.0.3-8
```

expected results:

```
2.6
```

Comment: Any relation to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45677720/7552)?

Comment: @glennjackman: Well, I ran across the mentioned issue while trying to provide an answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cut by decimal points using *printf* in `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%.1f\n", $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With single ***awk***:

```
hdp-select | awk '/hadoop-client/{ printf("%.1f\n",$NF); exit }'
2.6
```

---

- `/hadoop-client/` - considering only line with `hadoop-client` keyword
- `printf("%.1f\n",$NF)` - formatting version number as simple float number
- `exit` - stop processing immediately (resource saving)

Answer (score 1):

You could go with coreutils cut:

```
echo 2.6.0.3-8 | cut -d . -f 1,2
```

Output:

```
2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Sine you want to get basic version number so the command should be able to get at least `XX.YY` version number when if it is like `2.10.0.3.3-8`?

Below `grep` only command returning only `*.*` format of version.

```
grep -Po 'hadoop-client - \K[1-9]+\.[0-9]+(?=.*)' <(hdp-select)
2.6
```

A test:

```
grep -Po 'hadoop-client - \K[1-9]+\.[0-9]+(?=.*)' <<<"hadoop-client - 21.61.0.3-8"                 
21.61
```